# List full text indexes in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, index, full-text-search

Using SQL Server, it's possible to execute a query that [returns all the columns that contain a full text index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/949438/208318).

How can I do something similar using Oracle? Is it possible?

Comment: What do you define as a full text index in Oracle?  Are you talking about listing the Oracle Text indexes?

Comment: Here on dba.stackexchange (DBA.SE), users are encouraged to show what they have attempted themselves. Have you explored the system catalogue? You have a rep. of 3.6k on StackOverflow, you should know this.

Comment: @JustinCave Yes, probably. Full-text index is a SQL Server term, but I didn't know it was called differently in Oracle.

Comment: @Vérace I'm not very familiar with Oracle, but Google is my friend, and I did not post my question without some googling first. You took you time to look up my reputation just for the sake of being pedantic, maybe if you make better use of your time you can actually, you know, help people.

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 types of Text indexes in Oracle, owned by the `CTXSYS` user (installed optionally), so you can simply query `[DBA|ALL|USER]_INDEXES` and filter rows by the `ITYP_OWNER` and `ITYP_NAME` columns:

```
select
  *
from
  dba_indexes
where
  ityp_owner = 'CTXSYS'
  and ityp_name in ('CONTEXT', 'CTXCAT', 'CTXRULE', 'CTXXPATH')
;
```

Index types can be found in the `DBA_INDEXTYPES` view.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do the job but the databases I have access to at the moment do not have text indexes.  I will confirm later today.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ALL_INDEXES 
WHERE index_type = 'CONTEXT'
```

Comment: Looks like there are more options.   See: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_context_index.htm